# Can stackify prefix capture full response body?

Tags: c#, stackify

I have .net core project and add stackify prefix to monitor requests, but in response prefix show only headers but not body of response. It is possible to see all response body? 
On [prefix site](https://stackify.com/prefix-tips-and-tricks/) I found information:

> It can capture incoming post data, it can also capture the response and the response headers and part of the response body. Right now, we limit that to only be a certain amount of characters so if it’s returning something larger, it won’t capture all of it.

It is possible to change this?

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks, but it don't help me :( A better approach would be to allow this behaviour to change. I was hoping for some magical switch ;-)

Comment: They want to know if it's the free version?

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes, free version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to change this at the moment if the response body is too large it will not show up in the traces.

Stackify has an Ideas portal that you can make suggested changes to, their COO gets notified when a new request has been made and when a request has been up voted by several clients. He takes each request into good consideration and arranges them into Stackify's road map. Also you can subscribe to the ideas to keep updated on its progress. 
https://ideas.stackify.com

Comment: Thanks for information. Sad. A body of answers and requests would be very helpful in debugging.